# БАловать (разг?)

Tags: орфоэпия

Только что прошел [тест на граммар-наци](http://snob.ru/selected/entry/97286), там говорится, что в большом орфоэпическом словаре вариант б**а**ловать отмечен как разг.

Есть ли у кого-нибудь из участников этот словарь? Интересно, на самом ли деле, этот вариант в словаре дан как ***разг.*** В словаре М.В.Зарвы «Русское словесное ударение» нет данного слова. Зато в «Орфоэпическом словаре русского языка» под редакцией Р.И.Аванесова БАловать,***бАлую и бАлует, бАлованный отмечены в словаре запретительной пометой: **«не рек.».**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Только что прошел тест на граммар-наци, там говорится, что в **большом
>   орфоэпическом словаре** вариант б**а**ловать отмечен как разг.

Составители теста ошиблись.

В ***"Большом орфоэпическом словаре"***  (*Каленчук М. Л., Касаткин Л. Л., Касаткина Р. Ф.  "Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка. Литературное произношение и ударение начала ХХI века: норма и её варианты" , М.: АСТ-ПРЕСС КНИГА, 2012*), **на который ссылаются составители теста**,  пометы ***"разг."*** при слове ***баловать*** нет. В нём написано так:

> БАЛОВ**А**ТЬ, бал**у**ю, бал**у**ет; бал**у**ющий; бал**о**ванный ***и
>   допуст. младш.*** Б**А**ЛОВАТЬ, б**а**лую, б**а**лует;
>   б**а**лованный...

На первых страницах словаря говорится, что помета ***"и допуст."*** указывает лишь на меньшую употребительность  соответствующих вариантов  по сравнению с *неопомеченными*. Но тем не менее варианты с этой пометой **нормативны**  -- по мнению авторов **именно того словаря,** на который и пытались сослаться составители теста.

Отступления же от литературного произношения в ***"Большом орфоэпическом"*** помечаются так:

***! не рек.***

***! неправ.***

***! грубо неправ.***

Comment: Спасибо, Слава. Т.е. в официальной речи можно сказать БАловать?

Comment: В таком, к примеру, контексте: _"Нигде в мире государство так не **балует** свои нефтяные компании, как в России"?_ Во всяком случае, **бАлует** здесь будет звучать куда лучше, чем **балУет**.

Answer (score 4):

У меня есть словарь Л. Введенской для работников радио и телевидения (2012), там "бАловать" отмечено как просторечие.

В словаре Резниченко (2009) говорится, что"бАловать"  неуместно в строгой литературной речи. Отмечается вариативность ударения у поэтов:

За что нас только бабы бАлуют И губы, падая, дают,И выбегают за шлагбаумы, И от вагонов отстают? (Вознесенский)

Каменщик, каменщик в фартуке белом,Что ты там строишь? кому?
 - Эй, не мешай нам, мы заняты делом, Строим мы, строим тюрьму....- Каменщик, каменщик, вспомнит, пожалуй, Тех он, кто нес кирпичи!- Эй, берегись! под лесами не бАлуй...Знаем всё сами, молчи! (Брюсов).

Comment: Вариативность у поэтов ничуть не мешает народной и литературной вариативности. Я лично не люблю форму ***баловАть***, считаю ее рафинированной, манерной, салонной, слюнявой, давно устаревшей и изжившей себя.

Comment: Вера, да, ради рифмы, многие варианты допустимы.

Comment: Тем не менее,  Дерзкий Grantum, словари не спешать признать вариант с ударением на первом слоге. Мне тоже не нравится вариант на третьем слоге.

Comment: Мне кажется, что в поэзии форма "бАловать" не всегда используется ради рифмы. В приведенных примерах мы видим элементы звукозаписи  (повтор фонетически близких звуков) или изображение простонародных выражений (не бАлуй). Конечно, интересна история постановки ударения в этом глаголе (какая форма первична?), который происходит от слова бАл (бАять) - болтовня, разговоры. Может быть, менялась семантика: сначала ГОВОРИТЬ что-то приятное, потом  -  нежить, доставлять удовольствие или потворствовать капризам, прихотям.

Comment: Детям говорят : не бАлуйся, хватит бАловаться. Другого никогда не слышал.

Comment: Не могу сказать про  всех, но москвичи, как мне кажется,  чаще  говорят "не балУйся, хватит баловАться".  По другой форме узнаются приезжие. Еще я думаю, что изменение ударения может быть связано с фонетикой, то есть переносом его с первого слога в форме "баловаться" на третий слог.

Comment: Дерзкий Grantum, я тоже слышал "не бАлуйся". И раньше я тоже так говорил.

Comment: Серж, а сейчас как вы говорите?  Вернее, как вам удобнее говорить (если по зову сердца, по велению души)?

Comment: Вера, говорю, естественно баловАть. А удобней, конечно, бАловать. А теперь, судя по словарю, можно говорить и так и так.

Comment: Так же обстоит дело и с глаголом ''звонить''. Говорю: звонИт, но иногда срывается звОнит. Потому что во мне заложен именно этот вариант. Всегда говорил так.

Comment: _Vera: Не могу сказать про всех, но москвичи, как мне кажется, чаще говорят "не балУйся, хватит баловАться". По другой форме узнаются приезжие._ === Vera, рассмешили!

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего имется в виду произношение по "Большому орфоэпическому словарю" М. Л. Каленчук, Л. Л. Касаткина, Р. Ф. Касаткиной (М. "АСТ-Пресс Книга" - 2012. 1008 с.). В оцифрованном виде, я его ещё не встречал.

Кстати, когда ищете варианты произношения, в словарь Зарвы можно не заглядывать. Этот словарь делался на основе словаря для работников радио и телевидения, поэтому никаких вариантов произношения там нет. Даже хрестоматийное "твОрог-творОг" в словаре Зарвы представлено только одним вариантом.

Comment: Да, вы правы, Марк. речь идет именно об этом словаре.  В оцифрованном виде, я его ещё не встречал тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Серж, литературная орфоэпическая норма — балов**А**ть. Вариант с ударением на первый слог имеет место быть в непринужденном разговоре, вас за это никто не накажет. Однако всё-таки рекомендовано использовать литературное произношение.

Comment: Тагрикс, я прекрасно знаю, что литературное норма баловАть. Внимательно прочитайте вопрос.